# How can i fix fitafirma error with dim(x)?

Tags: r, arima

I have a problem with fitting fitafirma function.

I do have this code:

```
    fitarfima <- autoarfima(data = bby_ts, ar.max = 0, 
         ma.max = 0, criterion = "AIC", method = "full")
```

But I get the following error

> Error in apply(d[, 1:ar.max, ], 1, "sum") : dim(X) must have a positive length

My ts data is a simple vector with 2 columns. Could you help? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Improved code formatting.